# return value of which() if the condition does not find a match

Tags: r

Say, I have a data frame as follows

```
1 2
1 4
1 6
1 7
1 9
```

While running a loop from 1:10, I want to retrieve only those numbers which are present along with 1 in the table above, namely, 2,4,6,7,9. This is my code using the which condition, however, I get an error saying, "Error in if  : argument is of length zero". I also tried with ==TRUE instead of >0, and still get the same error.

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
 if(which((mydata[,1] == 1) & (mydata[,2] == i)) > 0)
 {
  print("yes");
 }
 else
 {
  print("no")
 }
}
```

Comment: Unnmatched `which` returns a _length_ zero vector not a zero; I guess it should be `if(length(which(..)) > 0) ...`

Comment: @alexis_laz , works, thanks.
Can you add the comment as an answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like suggested, you would have to check the `length` of `which`'s output:

```
if (length(which(mydata[,1] == 1 & mydata[,2] == i)) > 0)
```

A more appropriate tool for this is `any`:

```
if (any(mydata[,1] == 1 & mydata[,2] == i))
```

I also suggested removing the two sets of innermost parentheses since the `==` operator has higher precedence than `&` (see `?Syntax`).